# Finding a deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I do not have 10k+ on any exchange site, so I can’t search deleted questions I posted answers to.

I am looking for a question in one of the many Math sites, which asked for suggestions for the “center of the mathematical universe” (or something similar).

I know I posted an answer suggesting “Pythagoras’ Theorem”, and am pretty sure I used the expression “think about it”.

Any help finding the content of the question (and the other answers) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you authored an answer to a deleted question, you can view the answer and parent question if you have a link to it, but you can't view the other answers.

Comment: Some mods will help, assuming you know which site. In this case : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131800/where-is-the-belly-button-of-the-universe/131803#131803

Comment: @Catija Thank you!  For an ‘accept’, won’t you answer how did you locate it?

Answer (score 4):

In case you weren't aware of this, on any site you're a member of where you think your answer might possibly be located, click the Answers tab. Near the bottom there's a "recently deleted answers" link. If you click on it, you'll see all of your answers that have been deleted within the last 60 days, regardless of who or what did the deletion. I assume this will generally be a fairly short list, so you can search those entries.

Alternatively, if your answer was deleted just within the last few days, since the data for SEDE queries is only updated once a week, on Sunday it seems, you can possibly do a query on this data (see [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for more info). Otherwise, if your answer was deleted too long ago, I don't know of any specific way for you to do a search of deleted items. The only possible thing I can think of is if you can find some older archive copy of the SE data, where your answer exists but has not yet been deleted, which you can search directly, or download & search on your own machine.